# Python - Copy 'Sheet2' from xlsx file to another xlsx file

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

Writing a data cleansing script for csv and xlsx files using Python. One of the requirements is that the second sheet ('Sheet2') found in one of the raw xlsx input files ('RawFile.xlsx') be copied over to the xlsx output file ('OutputFile.xlsx') that my script is generating.

I considered simply saving Sheet2 as a df, as I did with Sheet1, and saving them together using ExcelWriter & df.to_excel, but Sheet2 has some odd formatting that must be maintained, including having empty rows at the top. Need an exact copy for the time being.

Please point me in the right direction if you can. Thanks, and let me know if you need anything else.